# SharePoint Office365 - How to Copy a List?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I'm setting up some SharePoint Lists in Office365. I've got one list set up just the way I want it and I want to create a new list which is almost exactly the same. I remember (way back when) I last worked with SharePoint about 6 years ago, you could copy a list to another list type but I can't seem to find this option.

I have looked around the Internet but so far, all the answers I have found have suggested using an 'Export List as Template' button in List Settings but I don't have this button.

My settings look like this
[image]

Is there a feature that I need to switch on to get this? This feels like it should be very easy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't see "Save this list as a template", check that Custom Scripts is not disabled in your SharePoint Admin settings.

Alternatively, I have been able to use other lists as templated by going to Site Contents in the Modern UI, select New > List and you should be presented with options to "Create a list" or "From an existing list"

[see Create list window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f3jH.png)

Answer (score 2):

From the **Site Content** Select **New** and then select **List**. This will open a another screen where you need to select **From an existing list** as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get list as Template, follow this steps.

- Go to the Site Contents
- Right Click on the List that you need to get template.
- Click on the Settings
- Then there is that option like image below.

[image]

Comment: Yes - I've seen this before but I do not have that button. I have the following options...
* Delete this list
* Permissions for this list
* Workflow Settings
* Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings

The issue I have is that the other options are not there. I've popped in a screenshot for clarity.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm the Administrator of the Office 365 Install

Comment: You can check it from Office Admin Dashboard.

Comment: What permissions should I have? I'm the Administrator?

Comment: @KeithJackson did you ever solve this?  I have the exact same issue.

Comment: @KeithJackson no what I wanted to hear but thanks. I read somewhere that workspaces created from Teams has limited functionality so I’m wondering if that was the reason for my issue.

Comment: @Skin - I think that's what I assumed in the end - I may have been wrong but I wasn't dealing with a massive amount of data.